# Print images from a form using javascript or php

Tags: php, javascript

I have created a registration form  which reads user data and send it to other php page which shows all the entered details. I was able to send its data to other php page using **$_POST[]** ,
but I am not able to send the images.

---

the below code is for the upload button which takes the image from user

```
<tr>
<td>Upload Image :</td>
<td><INPUT TYPE="file" NAME="image" required="required"></td>
</tr>
```

I have tried this using php but no luck

```
<? php 
$img = $_POST['image'];
echo echo "<img src=$img>" ?>
```

So what could I do to send an image from one page to another using javascript or php?

Comment: You should check the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: oh thank u for d help.
i will try to correct the upload method first

Answer (score 0):

The file selected by the user is sent over as data, so you have to pick up this data, save it somewhere, and then it is that "somewhere" that you would echo in an IMG tag.

W3Schools has an example of uploading and saving an image that you could adapt: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: that means i was doing everything wrong.
thnx buddy , i think i need to start from scratch

Answer (score 0):

upload the file, move it from temp to a folder, display it from that folder

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Image:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

and

```
  <? php 
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "<img src= 'upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "'>";


  ?>
```

done

Comment: getting error in the last line of the code .   it is printing >"?

Comment: what is it printing? it works for me.. http://stackover1.comeze.com/4/ look at the source code and you can see that img link is correctly printed..
maybe if you post your exact code or the link to your webpage it could help..

Comment: finally got it thanx :)
i had not created the upload folder

Comment: if this solved your problem mark this as the correct answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in you uploading script.. To improve it:
HTML code:

```
<tr>
<td>Upload Image :</td>
<td>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploader" id="uploader">
<input type="file" name="image" required="required">
<input name="upl" type="submit" id="upl" value="Upload">
</form></td>
</tr>
```

PHP code:

```
if( $_POST['upl'] == 'Upload') {
$img = 'images/'.$_FILES['image']['name'];
if(@copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$img)) echo '<img src="'.$img.'">';
else echo 'ERROR!';
}
```

Comment: i am getting some error "Notice: Undefined index: image in E:\xampp\htdocs\series\firstfile\user_profile.php on line 28
ERROR!""

this is the line where i have wrote ur php code

Comment: first.. create the directory images.. then use this script